# Seeking issue with mp4 and videojs (occurring in chrome)

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video, video.js

I have an issue that is occurring if you try and seek a few times to different points in the video. Eventually you end up getting an error saying it's a network issue. If I download the file from the server it's fine and if I don't seek to much it's fine as well.

Wondering if anyone knows what the issue might be.

Here is an example: https://www.la1tv.co.uk/player/107/195
Just jump around a bit (in chrome) and you should get the error. I have attached a screenshot.

Thanks!

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfsWg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was not sending a header with an etag in the response containing the video. Adding the etag header (which in my case is the file id) solved the problem.

Here is some information about etags: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag